C++: std::shared_ptr and memory_order
I know that the typical recommended implementation of std::shared_ptr implies that the counter is incremented with the relaxed mode while the decrement operation needs the release mode (and, if it happens that it is the last reference, the acquire fence is followed by the deletion of a control block).
Consider the following code:
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

std::atomic_bool ab{false};

int main()
{
    auto iPtr = std::make_shared<int>(5);
    std::thread thr{[iPtr] // here is sth like counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order::relaxed)
    {
        while (!ab.load(std::memory_order::relaxed));
        assert(*iPtr == 6); // B

        // (destructor) here is sth like counter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) followed by std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire)
    }};

    *iPtr = 6; // A
    iPtr.reset(); // here is sth like counter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release)

    ab.store(true, std::memory_order::relaxed);
    
    thr.join();
}

Could the assert actually fail?
My assumption would be yes. Although we perform a release operation in iPtr.reset();, we do not have a corresponding acquire operation before the assert which would "update" the memory, so we can't say that A synchronizes-with and, therefore, happens-before B.
Am I right in my understanding?
Note: I set the relaxed mode for ab on purpose, so that there woudn't be unexpected synchronized-with relationship formed by it. Therefore, the only synchronizations that really take place are those induced by the shared_ptr's counter

Your analysis sounds correct to me.

The way I'd phrase it is that there is nothig before the assert that acquiringly observes the released value. counter is never even accessed in the region of interest.

That sounds correct.  The synchronization in std::shared_ptr is just there to make sure the reference counts are consistent.  It's the application writer's job to ensure access to the pointed-to object is correctly synchronized.

Thank you all for the answers.
Actually, will the situation change if we put std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire) before the assert?

@Denis That won't change anything, because there is no read of the reference count in the thread. And either way, there is no guarantee that shared_ptr contains a release operation like you describe. That's an implementation detail without any corresponding guarantee in the specification.
